# Joining on 3 different keys as they're set

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have these tables:

```
TABLE vessels
ID int PK
organization_id int FK
fleet_id int FK
name VARCHAR

TABLE settings
ID int PK
organization_id int NULL FK
fleet_id int NULL FK
vessel_id int NULL FK
some_value INT
```

In table settings, `some_value` can be either 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 or 7

Some entries in the `settings` table are linked to a `vessel_id` based on it's `fleet_id` or `organization_id`

How do I go about selecting the settings for a `vessel`, if a vessel has settings via it's `fleet_id` or `organization_id` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way that results my needs better:

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  IFNULL(s1.some_value, IFNULL(s2.some_value, s3.some_value)) as some_value
FROM
  vessels a
JOIN
  settings s1 ON a.id = s1.vessel_id
JOIN
  settings s2 ON a.fleet_id = s2.fleet_id
JOIN
  settings s3 ON a.organization_id = s3.organization_id
```

Might not be the fastest query, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT settings.* FROM vessels INNER JOIN settings ON setting.organization_id=vessel.id
UNION
SELECT settings.* FROM vessels INNER JOIN settings ON setting.fleet_id=vessel.id
UNION
SELECT settings.* FROM vessels INNER JOIN settings ON setting.vessel_id=vessel.id
```